# How do I fetch the contents entered in the Input field using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm having an input field in the form where the users updates their Name on click of a button. This change in the input field should be captured by the Ajax and update it.

Html -

```
<p id="name"><%= @current_user.name %></p>

<button type="button" id="namebtn">&#xE254;</i> </button>
```

coffee Script -

```
$('form').on 'focusout', ->
    $elem = $(this)
    if !$elem.find(':focus').length
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:3000/profile/name_change",
                data: "{
                    'name': '"+$('#name').val()+"'}",
            })
        return
```

How do I capture the changed input from the input field?

Comment: Yes, I'm capturing them on focus out. It will be initially a p element, on click on a button, it'll change into editable text. Now when it gets changed, I need to capture the input and pass it using Ajax asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you have an 'input field', yet `#name` is clearly a `p` element. You need to use `text()` to get its value in that case.

Also note that your use of `focusout` on the form whilst checking the `:focus` element is rather odd. You could just use a standard `click` handler instead:

```
$('#namebtn').on 'click', ->
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/profile/name_change",
    data: { name: $('#name').text() }
  })
  return
```

Comment: Thanks Man that was very helpful!

Comment: Heyy, Can you help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45597470/5507100